# Read an INSPIRE GML in QGIS2.0 : gml:xlink resolving

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, gml, inspire

I'm trying to read an INSPIRE GML, which contains internal and external links between the elements. I saw on the GDAL site that we can set environment variable in order to load this link in QGIS (http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_gml.html) but it seems it doesn't work on this QGIS version.

The impacted lines look like this one:

Does someone have some experience in integration of this type of model?

Comment: Could you show how impacted lines look like? It is not included in the question...

Comment: The only Inspire schema that GDAL can resolve without further development is the CadastralParcels schema. Is that the one you are trying to use?

Comment: I've put an example online [here](http://geoshopmap.noel.gv.at/RoadTransportNetwork.xml). It's a single community road transport network consisting of RoadNode, RoadLinks, Transport Network List and Road List. In the GML/XML the RoadLinks are Xlinked to the Roads they are associated with and also the network they are contained in. In QGIS there is no chance to use this associations, for example to select all RoadLinks of a certain TransportNetwork. Even the references simply get hidden in the attribute table.

Answer (score 1):

I made some tests as-well and, as expected, it seems QGIS does not support the INSPIRE format based on GML3.2 (with xlink). The possible solutions are:

- If you really need QGIS, to use another more "interoperable" format truly supported (see [this page](http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/supported_data.html)). Keep in mind that, by chance, INSPIRE legislation does not impose GML - anybody implementing INSPIRE is free to use whatever encoding format.
- To use another software (!). Unfortunately, nobody has ever heard about any GIS software fully supporting INSPIRE GML format... Hope springs eternal :-)

Comment: I was just wondering if any GIS (QGIS as a reference) is able to make use of the more or less object-oriented data model INSPIRE is introducing. Furthermore object references as xlinks is a GML definition and not INSPIRE specific. I don't see the sense of harmonizing data into a object-oriented data model and than flattening it to any data encoding just as anybody finds it fits best. Where is the harmonization then (for example try to build a graph over national borders when RoadLink to RoadNode references are differing). Therefore I still hope for your latter point ... thx for your testing ;)

Comment: Ok, since there are no more answers being introduced to this, you deserve the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple QGIS Plugin for further testing.
http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/gmlloader/

1. Install the Plugin "GML Loader" using the QGIS Plugin Manager. Be sure to enable "display Experimental Plugins" first. You will find the plugin under "Vector / GML Loader".
2. Enable "Resolve elements" / "Convert attributes to fields"
3. Add an optional .gfs file.
4. Open the .gml file.

Your comment is highly appreciated.

[image: QGIS GML Loader]

Answer (score 0):

As defined in the provided link https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/gml.html#gml-xlink-resolving you can do this in QGIS by setting the environment as follows

[image]